# How to configure the MVC portlet to use the keys from Language_forCustomer.properties?

Tags: internationalization, liferay, portlet, liferay-7

I have a requirement on jsp labels keys which are in (*.jsp) page I need to call the keys from the specific `.properties` file knowing that each customer has a `.properties file`.
I already posted this ( well explained ) in the liferay forum but still waiting any support!

and to avoid the Cross-referencing This is the link of the thread

https://liferay.dev/forums/-/message_boards/message/119910224

All in all my question is :

> How to make <liferay-ui:message key="key-for-customer-1" /> for the
> login.jsp read the key from the Language_customer1.properties under
> /resource/content/ folder ?